# Head word for Synonyms and Word Families?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a word/term/phrase that means the designated word to represent a collection of related words?

Dictionaries use a "head" or "root" word for variants (House: >Houses, >Housing, >Housed) - is there such a thing for Synonyms and Word Families?

I've Googled and I've searched here (and Yahoo Answers etc.).
I'm not sure if there is such a term.

If there is, can someone please tell me the name?
If there is, can someone point to a source (such as a thesaurus that uses it)?

If there is no such term/reference - what would you suggest as a way to implement it?
Should I simply go for the shortest word in the group (with the same/similar part of speech/morphological attributes (mood/gender etc.)?
Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://mseffie.com/assignments/roots/Root%20Sets.pdf) is a bunch of **Root words**. Probably not exactly what you're thinking of, but there's no reason not to call *house* a "root word" in your example. The other words in a "family" like yours can reasonably be called **derivatives**. In most cases, any etymological dictionary should usually make it obvious to you which word in a set is best designated as the "root" (often, but not necessarily, the shortest).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers - yes, most dictionaries will carry that information.  What I'm looking for is for broader/wider word-groups/relations ... such as those of Synonyms (tight/loose), and word-families (associated).  If it helps, think of synonyms for "house" : dwelling, abode, domicile etc.  Is there a standard that dictates 1 of those synonyms to represent the "collective"?  If so, what is the term for such a representative?

Comment: This is probably a linguistics question.  Suggestion: try asking this question and the previous one on linguistics.se and see what kind of responses you get there.  Note that linguistics.se is smaller and might take a little longer to get feedback.

Comment: Regarding your question "what would you suggest as a way to implement it".  Implement what?  (Is that a software dev question?)

Comment: @theclueless1: I think we have to skirt carefully round this one. Strictly speaking I think you may be either looking for resources, or asking for feedback regarding a "word categorisation system" you have in mind - both of which would be Off Topic. I don't know any better terms than *root word* and *derivatives* for the On Topic aspect of the question, but CoolHandLouis may well be right that *taken as a whole* your question may be a better fit on linguistics. Certainly it's not exactly getting anywhere here, but I wish you luck with it wherever it ends up.

Comment: Seems related to [[Google Search: synsets](https://www.google.com/search?q=synset&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=g0sWU6bNBNPIkAfWzYGwCw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=1093&bih=545&dpr=1.25)] = "In metadata a synonym ring or synset, is a group of data elements that are considered semantically equivalent for the purposes of information retrieval." (wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

Onomasiology : [the study of words and expressions having similar or associated concepts and a basis (as social, regional, occupational) for being grouped](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/253839/onomasiology)